# Encontrar a linha com maior quantidade de colunas true - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

Table User

| estado_id | user_id | shopping | mercado | feira |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Table Cidade

| estado_id | version_id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | jose | shopping |
| 1 | 2 | maria | feira |
| 1 | 2 | maria | mercado |
| 1 | 3 | bruna | mercado |

Preciso comparar os estados, e trazer só os que abrangem o usuário x, porém a coluna version_id podem existir centenas de dados, apenas devo retornar aos quais o usuário x esteja ligada. Na tabela usuários preciso trazer todos que deem match. Se na tabela shopping e feira o valor for 1 e mercado for 0 então só shopping e feira devem ser retornado dentro destas centenas de versões, eu consegui trazer somente até os dados do usuário/estado_id porem quando faz a comparação do da tabela de usuário = 1 com a tabela de cidades type=shooping eu nao consegui pois precisa ser dinâmico

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT cidade.*,uv.user_id, uv.shopping, uv.mercado, uv.feira
   FROM cidade
  INNER JOIN users2 as uv 
     ON cidade.estado_id = uv.estado_id
  WHERE cidade.estado_id = 1 
    AND uv.user_id = 1) 
SELECT [type], shopping, mercado, feira FROM CTE
```

A expectativa seria

| estado_id | version_id | name | type | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | jose | shopping | 1 |

Pois joão tem shopping e feira como true(1)

Comment: sinceramente a lógica é consfusa no que explicou por isso não vou escrever uma resposta, mas focando na dúvida do título, pode somar a quantidade de colunas bit que estiver true usando isso no select `sum(cast(shopping as int)+cast(mercado as int)+cast(feira as int)) as soma` e depois usar isso para ordenar or fazer `having` e ter o resultado com maior valor

Comment: se o cast de bit>int não funcionar bem no mysql, pode fazer isso tbm: `sum(mercado * 1) + sum(feira * 1) + sum(feira * 1) as soma`